# Calculate the number of tiling combinations

Tags: combinatorics

[image: Problem Statement]
[image: Problem Statement]

Source - Zonal Informatics Olympiad 2006 Question Paper

Have tried deriving the answer through solutions to smaller problems, but of no avail.

Comment: Try coming up with two recurrence relations, one for a flat edge and one for a bumpy edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Now incorporating EuYu's comment:*

If $f(n)$ is the number of ways of tiling a $2 \times n$ rectangle then $$f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)+2\sum_{j\lt n-2}f(j)$$ starting at $f(0)=1$, since the right hand end can be a vertical double tile, two horizontal double tiles, or in two orientations an L on the end with repeating horizontal doubles eventually capped by another L.

You can now answer the particular questions by hand, or by noting this is also $$f(n)=2f(n-1)+f(n-3)$$ starting at $f(0)=f(1)=1$, with the generating function $1/(1-2x-x^3),$ or just look up [OEIS A052980](http://oeis.org/A052980) .

Comment: Not quite true, how about an $L$ on the end with repeating horizontal doubles eventually capped by another $L$.

Comment: @EuYu: very true.

Comment: Works like a charm! Could you also please elaborate on how you derived the function?

Comment: @7Aces: the first function comes for removing the first height 2 rectangle at the right, the second by looking at $f(n)-f(n-1)$.